# Two different Python max() function articles in GeeksForGeeks?

Tags: python

I was reading about the key argument in max() in Python and came across two articles in GeeksForGeeks.

1. [First article: Python – max() function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-max-function/)
2. [Second article: Python String | max()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-max/).

In the first article, Example 2 reads: "By default, *max()* will return the string with the maximum lexicographic value" and gave the following sample code which prints "for".

```
var1 = "geeks"
var2 = "for"
var3 = "geek"
 
max_val = max(var1, var2, var3)
print(max_val) 
# "for"
```

However, when I plugged that code in my IDE, it prints "geeks". Am I missing something here or is there an error in the article?

I also read Python's [official doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#max) but it didn't address the question.

I've tried the following codes on my own IDE and the outcome is exactly as expected.

```
var1 = "geeks"
var2 = "for"
var3 = "geek"

print(max(var1, var2, var3))
# prints "geeks"

lst1 = ["geeks", "for", "geek"]
print(max(lst1)) 
# prints "geeks"

print(max('aa','az')) 
# prints 'az' since it has the highest "lexicographic value" aka alphabetical order
```

Comment: It seems they mixed up "max" and "min".

Comment: Yes, the article is wrong. "geeks" is the "largest" of the values. It would come last in a dictionary.

Comment: Lesson is: don't read Geeks for Geeks. Try https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F.

Comment: Thank you all for reaffirming! I was losing my mind thinking that I can't alphabet LOL @cup mentioned that there is another Example 2 farther down in the article where it compared "Geeks" "for" and "Geek" and the correct output is indeed "for" in that case because of the capitalized "g". Base on that I'm guessing they made an error in the capitalization in the first Example 2. Lesson for the day: Uppercase letters have lower lexicographical value.

Answer (score -2):

The article is incorrect in one place and correct in another - you've typed the data incorrectly.  It has Geeks: not geeks.  Geeks has a lower lexicographical value than for, geeks has a higher one.

Comment: I'm seeing lowercase g geeks https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-max-function/

Comment: Look at the 2nd example: the one that says **Example 2: Finding the lexicographically maximum string in a string list**

Comment: Comically, there are two examples named "example 2" on that page, the first one has lowercase `g` and the second has uppercase `G`. Just in case anyone thought geeksforgeeks.com was a reputable site.

Comment: @kaya3 Thank you for pointing that out! I did not read far enough to see that there are two "example 2". The second example 2 has the correct output since capitalized letters have lower lexicographical value as cup stated.